# It is only displaying 1 row when inserting values

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

My code below is supposed to display each question ($_POST[questionText]). For each question, it displays it's SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent and OptionId. But instead it is only displaying 1 question. Why is it only displaying 1 question and how can I get it to display all of the questions?

I use an echo to text the output with the INSERT VALUES.

```
foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $i => $question)
{

      $insertquestion = array();


$options[] = $_POST['gridValues'];

switch ($options[$i]){

    case "3": 
    $selected_option = "A-C";
    break;

    case "4": 
    $selected_option = "A-D";
    break;

    default:
    $selected_option = "";
    break;

}      

$optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = '". mysql_real_escape_string($selected_option)."')";

 $optionrs = mysql_query($optionquery);
 $optionrecord = mysql_fetch_array($optionrs);
 $optionid = $optionrecord['OptionId']; 


    $insertquestion[] = "'". mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id'] ) . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ."' ,'". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['num_questions'] ) ."','".  mysql_real_escape_string( $question ) ."','".  mysql_real_escape_string( $optionid ) ."'";

    $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) 
    VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";

    $i++;

    }

echo($questionsql);
```

Below is the javascript code and form code. How it works is the user types in a question in the textarea `('name='questionText')` and types in an option `(name='gridValues')` and then they append them two in a table row (table in the form which `id='qandatbl'`). This is the question 1. Then they do the same again for second question, then third and etc. Please look at this carefully, it is easy to follow.

```
<script>

    function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $question = $("<td class='question'></td>");
    var $options = $("<td class='option'></td>");
    var $questionType = '';

    $('#questionTextArea').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                   .attr('value',$this.val())

    $question.append($questionText);

    });

    $('.gridTxt', context).each( function() {

     var $this = $(this);
     var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                     .attr('value',$this.val())

    $options.append($optionsText);
    $questionType = $this.val();

    });

    $tr.append($question);
    $tr.append($options);    
    $tbody.append($tr); 

    }

</script>

    <form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" >

    <h1>SESSION (<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>)</h1>

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Question:</td> 
        <td rowspan="3">
            <textarea id="questionTextArea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
    <tr class="option">
    <td>Option Type:</td>
    <td>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="gridValues" class="gridTxt maxRow" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="qandatbl" align="center">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="question">Question</th>
        <th class="option">Option Type</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    </form>
```

Comment: you shouldn't be posting your question over and over again. why?

Comment: Because I need to get this part done so I can get on the next part of the work. I was up till 6am to try and figure it out yesterday but couldn't figure it out and I have wastewd a lot of time on this issue

Comment: that is because your question isn't clear - do you get several questions displayed on the page before you submit? after submit - is your `$_POST['questionText']` is actually an array?

Comment: @Elen Before I submit my questions I can submit as many questions as I want . I append all of my questions (lets say I have 5 questions) in a table, 1 table in each row, when I submit the form, I see the echo $questionsql and all it does is echo only the question from the final row that has been appended, it doesn't echo any other question. It doesn't matter if I have appended 5 questions or 100 questions, it will only echo 1 question which is the last question appended.

Comment: @Elen I meant to say 1 question in each row appended, not 1 table in each row appended, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first. can you please change you java script to:

```
var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                     .attr('value',$this.val())
```

then your php code to:

---

UPDATE

```
$i = 0;
$c = count($_POST['gridValues']);

print_r($_POST['questionText']);
print_r( $_POST['gridValues'] );

$insertquestion = array();

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){

    switch ($_POST['gridValues'][$i]){
        case "3": 
        $selected_option = "A-C";
        break;
        case "4": 
        $selected_option = "A-D";
        break;
        default:
        $selected_option = "";
        break;
    }      

    $optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = '". mysql_real_escape_string($selected_option)."')";
    $optionrs = mysql_query($optionquery);
    $optionrecord = mysql_fetch_array($optionrs);
    $optionid = $optionrecord['OptionId']; 

    $insertquestion[] = "'". mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id'] ) . 
                    ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ."' ,'". 
                    mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['num_questions'] ) ."','".  
                    mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['questionText'][$i] ) ."','".  
                    mysql_real_escape_string( $optionid ) ."'";

}

 $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) 
    VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";

echo($questionsql);
```

Comment: This is the outcome it has come below: (I have appended 2 questions, first question 'what's my name', second question 'what's my age'.)`Array ( [0] => what's my name [1] => what's my age )
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in Mobile_app/insertQuestion.php on line 36
INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) VALUES ('WYO' ,'3','what's my age','')`. I just want to say that the optionId is not appearing in the echo. I will add in next comment why I think this is

Comment: ok. under what  switch option falls question `what's my age` - because to me it looks like it falls under default - which is **empty**

Comment: I think the reason the OptionId is not appearing because in my javascript where I include +"[]" in var $optionText, the code is actually this:   `var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' /><span href='#' class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
         .attr('value',$this.val())` I have a hyperlink next to the textbox which I need and I think that may affect the $name attribute but Im not sure

Comment: For the switch option, the second question had option '4' in the textbox which is `$_POST['gridValues'];`, number '4' should match case '4' in the switch statement which is 'A-D' and in my database, 'OptionType' 'A-D' equals 'OptionId' 'O2' so O2 should be displayed for the OptionId in the $questionsql

Comment: well it is not what you originally posted?.. yes you need to apply attribute `name` to `input` only.

Comment: can you please add the following after `print_r($_POST['questionText']);` - `print_r($_POST['gridValues'];);` - and run it again and post the outcome?

Comment: sorry I meant second question not first question.

Comment: the outcome when doing a print_r for gridValues is this: `Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 4 )`

Comment: well that tells us that your grid does send correct values for gridValues now - yes?

Comment: Yes it does, grid values are correct, if I remove the +"[]" then it displays the optionId in the echo but it is because I have a hyperlink next to the textbox that +"[]" isn't working because of the hyperlink comes straight after the input and a name attribute can't be given to a hyperlink like you already stated

Comment: This has worked as it now displays both questions. Can I ask one final question though. How can I change this code below where it contains the +"[]" because if I keep in then it means the hyperlink doesn't work as it won't open up the grid:   `var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' /><span href='#' class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
         .attr('value',$this.val())
`

Comment: try `var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]") .attr('value',$this.val())` - i guess it doesn't work for sql query without `[ ]`?

Comment: you're right I need the +"[]" to get the multiple questions to be displayed in the output but I need the hyperlink as well. Everytime the user appends a question into a tablerow it needs to display this textbox and the hyperlink, just in case the user wants to change an option then they can click on the link to open the grid and select another option. So if I do what you have said, then how can I display the hyperlink next to the textbox? Do I need to concatenate the textbox and hyperlink together or something like that?

Comment: you need to add your span later, try: `var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]").attr('value',$this.val()).after("<span href='#' class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>");` and i would appreciate if you mark my answer as accepted, since the code worked.

Comment: I will mark your answer definetly and I will mark your answer on the previous question of this posted yesterday because of the help you have given me :) I will try the code in the comment above to see if hyperlink works after coming after the array.

Comment: I have tried your coding with the .after() but it doesn't display the hyperlink if I do this.

Comment: post a separate question with your java script code + html only. perhaps you need to do .each()

Comment: Ok I will do that. Thank you :) for your help, appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from your code, it's doing this...

```
foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $i => $question)
{
    // insert the row
    $questionsql = '...';
    $i++;
    }
echo($questionsql);
```

So `$questionsql` is output right at the end of the loop, at which point it will contain data from only the last iteration.

If you want `$questionsql` to be output for each inserted row, it needs to go inside the loop.

Comment: Elen has solved the problem of inserting multiple questions. I just have 1 little problem I need to address which you can find out from read the last couple of comments below Elen's questionn if you fancy helping. It's about including the +"[]" but also including the hyperlink

Comment: @user1309180 I suggest you ask questions as a question instead of a comment (and mark the accepted answer as accepted so that others don't waste time answering the headline question which is already answered).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#questionTextArea').each( function() {
...
}
```

This part of the function is going to only cause one iteration of the function to happen.  Your using an id selector(unique) and the each function in combination.  So your selecting one element and then using the each function to iterate over the one object.

Comment: from yesterday's post i understood that he don't get array of `$_POST['questionText']` - the php code above i provided, yet he is saying he only gets echoed 1 insert query for 1 question.... it's not clear... except that `$options[] = $_POST['gridValues'];` should be outside of `foreach`

Comment: To make it easier to understand my echo is showing this below if I have 7 questions questions: INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, OptionId) VALUES ('ABV', '8', 'what's my name', 'O5'). It is only going to INSERT one question (one row) and that is the latest question entered. #it does not INSERT the other questions?